# Instagram API - Can I search for users with more than X followers

Tags: web, instagram, instagram-api

I couldn't find this option in the API so it might not be possible, but is there a way to search for users with more than a specific amount of followers?
If not, is there a way (in the api) the find "popular" users or users that started gaining a big amount of followers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no API to get users directly with certain follower count criteria.

You can search for a hashtag using API and check the like count and determine how popular the user is and then make another USER API call to get that user details.

Comment: could you please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077540/why-instagram-api-does-not-return-more-than-2-users-in-search-using-sandbox? :)